# removing the first 3 rows of a group with conditional statement in r

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, conditional-statements

I would like to remove rows that are not fulfilling the condition that I want. For example:

```
Event   Value
  1       1
  1       0
  1       0
  1       0
  2       8
  2       7
  2       1
  2       0
  2       0
  2       0
  3       8
  3       0
  3       0
  3       0
  3       0
```

If per event, in the column of value there is a number higher than 2 (Value > 2) remove the first 3 rows starting from that Value that is not fulfilling the criteria.
It should look like this:

```
Event   Value
  1       1
  1       0
  1       0
  1       0
  2       0
  2       0
  3       0
  3       0
```

I have been able to remove the first row of each Event that accomplish the criteria, but haven't find a way to remove the other rows.

```
Event<- c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3)  
Value<- c(1,0,0,0,8,7,1,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,0)
A<- data.frame(Event, Value)

  A %>%
  group_by(Event) %>%
  filter(!(Value >= 2 & row_number() == 1))
```

Any idea?

Comment: If you have multiple blocks of values greater than 2, what would be the output i.e. for Event 2, if the 'Value' is 8 5 0 3 2

Comment: In the dataframe I have that would no be the case, but if that happens then delete all the event.

Comment: You can try `A %>% group_by(Event) %>% slice(if(any(Value >=2)) -(which(Value >=2)[1]  + 0:2) else row_number())`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an option with `slice`.  After grouping by 'Event', check `if` there are `any` 'Value' greater than or equal to 2, then return the negative index of the sequence from the first occurrence of that case or `else` return the `row_number()`.  The negative index removes those rows

```
library(dplyr)
A %>% 
     group_by(Event) %>% 
     slice(if(any(Value >=2)) -(which(Value >=2)[1] + 0:2) else row_number())
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a question, in the example, the event 2 should start counting the deleting of the rows from the Value 7, so it should delete the row of the value 8 and also the rows of the 7,1 and 0. Any way to fix the code to do it?

Comment: @Noel So, is it not from the beginning the 3 rows?

Comment: @Noel sorry, can you please update your post with an example and I have some doubts regardiing that logic

Comment: I was able to solve it with your idea. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Hey @akrun, I'm having some troubles. If Instead of deleting rows, I want to assign NAs to every event that has in their first row a Value higher than 2. So, if an event is having in it's first row a Value higher than 2, I want to assign NA to that row, and to the coming two rows of that event. If the event doesn't have more rows, just the rows the event has.

Comment: Here is an example, with a column of the desire output I want. 
Event<- c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,4,5,6,6,6)  
Value<- c(1,0,8,0,8,8,7,1,10,4,0,1,10,3,0,0)
Desire_output<- c(1,0,8,0,8,NA, NA, NA,0,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA)
AAA<- data.frame(Event, Value, Desire_output)
please let me know if you hav an idea, and thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: @Noel can you please post as a new question so that it makes it easier

Comment: sure its done. Here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61467044/dealing-dataframes-with-conditional-statements